# 「Cent OS」 の 「Yum リポジトリ設定」は、redhatの製品マニュアルを参考に出来る？

Tags: centos, redhat

**「Cent OS」 の 「Yum リポジトリ設定」について調べていたら、[redhatの製品マニュアル](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/ja-JP/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Configuring_Yum_and_Yum_Repositories.html)が見つかったのですが、このページはどの程度参考に出来るのでしょうか？**

**Q1.「Cent OS」におけるリポジトリ設定とどれぐらい異なる？**
・全く同じ？
・一部は同じ？
・全然異なる？

**Q2.yumのコマンドというよりは、「Cent OS」のどこにどういう優先順位でリポジトリ関係ファイルが配置されるか知りたいのですが、そういうことを掲載している公式サイトみたいなのはないでしょうか？**
・manページですか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> このページはどの程度参考に出来るのでしょうか？

Centosの上流のディストリビューションがRHELですので参照しているドキュメントとCentOSのバージョンが一致していれば「何を基にしているか」という意味では参考になると思います。また、CentOSの立ち位置を考えると 大抵の事は RHEL と同じだと思います。

> Q1.「Cent OS」におけるリポジトリ設定とどれぐらい異なる？

参照しているリポジトリがそれぞれ違うので同じではありません。

> Q2.yumのコマンドというよりは、「Cent OS」のどこにどういう優先順位でリポジトリ関係ファイルが配置されるか知りたいのですが、そういうことを掲載している公式サイトみたいなのはないでしょうか？

知りたいことが書いてあるかわかりませんが公式ドキュメントはこの辺でしょうか。

man yum

man yum.conf

https://wiki.centos.org/PackageManagement/Yum

http://yum.baseurl.org/

Comment: なるほど、バージョンも大事なのですね。またリンク提示ありがとうございました。参考になりました